# Is it faster to allow from a long list of IP groups, or deny from a longer list in Apache .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

If I am trying to set up an .htaccess file to only allow traffic from a specific geographic region using [this](https://www.countryipblocks.net/acl.php) tool, will the server have better performance if I say:

```
DENY FROM ALL
ALLOW FROM ....
ALLOW FROM ....
....
ALLOW FROM
```

or would it be better if I said this:

```
ALLOW FROM ALL
DENY FROM ....
DENY FROM ....
....
DENY FROM
```

where that list would be an order of magnitude longer, if not more?

My instinct tells me that denying from all and then allowing groups and ranges of IP addresses would be faster because that is a shorter list to check against, but I don't know enough about how Apache handles this scenario.

Comment: Why don't you simply test it? Make a test setup with 1000 addresses and time the processing.

Comment: And a side note: please keep in mind that the directives you are using are outdated. They have been deprecated for the apache http server in versions 2.4 and above (which is the clear majority of the operated http server's today).